# Does ClipIT help to track data's source and destination?

Tags: clipboard, clipboard-manager

I know that ClipIt saves history of last copied items.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to know what is the source and destination of each copied item ?
- If not, is there other clipboard manager that can do that??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple answers:

No and … no.

---

The reason, it makes no sense to save these additionally information in a clipboard manager.